# How can I set cursor position in a input on android browser using javascript

Tags: javascript, android-browser

I want to set cursor position for input on android browser. I am using the following code:

```
function setCaretPosition(ctrl, pos)
{

    if(ctrl.setSelectionRange)
    {
        ctrl.focus();
        ctrl.setSelectionRange(pos,pos);
    }
    else if (ctrl.createTextRange) {
        var range = ctrl.createTextRange();
        range.collapse(true);
        range.moveEnd('character', pos);
        range.moveStart('character', pos);
        range.select();
    }
}
```

however "ctrl.setSelectionRange(pos,pos);" does not seem to work on android browser. It's working on desktop. anyone knows how to set cursor position for input on android browser?

Actually the reason why I want to set cursor position is that I want to disable some character when user input. I am using replace() with regular expression binding on oninput event. the problem is after replacing the cursor goes to the end of the text in the input. I want to keep the cursor at the same position when user input(user may move the cursor in the middle of the text and input some character which I don't want them to input).

Answer (score 0):

use **keypress** event, you can restrict text input before it was actually added, instead of removing in After.
http://jsfiddle.net/xwuxR/

```
 function acceptText(){       
   if(event.charCode < 48 || event.charCode>57)
      event.preventDefault();
  }
```

sample shows input available for numbers only